# How to correctly garbage collect objects using Operator SDK?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, operator-sdk

The Operator-SDK for Kubernetes Operators has a [`ctrl.SetControllerReference()`](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/controller/controllerutil#SetControllerReference) function, which claims it enables automatically garbage collecting objects when the managing Custom Resource is deleted.

Sometimes it doesn't seem to delete anything. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl.SetControllerReference()` only changes `metadata.ownerReferences` on the local object.

It doesn't automatically call `reconciler.Update()` for you.
So the changes were never persisted, and the `Owner` never changed.

The correct way to create an object is to call `ctrl.SetControllerReference()` before you call `reconciler.Create()`, e.g.

```golang
if err := ctrl.SetControllerReference(mycrd, secret, r.Scheme); err != nil {
    log.Error(err, "Failed to set controller reference")
    return err
}

log.Info("Creating a new Secret", "Secret.Namespace", secret.Namespace, "Secret.Name", secret.Name)
if err = r.Create(ctx, secret); err != nil {
    log.Error(err, "Failed to create new Secret", "Secret.Namespace", secret.Namespace, "Secret.Name", secret.Name)
    return err
}
```